# Performance of thermoelectric generator

Tags: generator, peltier, power-generation

I would like to build a self-powered device on the surface of a vehicle without modifying it.

It is possible to generate enough power though thermoelectric generator by the temperature difference of the car surface (around 60~70 deg C) and street temperature?

What is the power output per unit area of a common thermoelectric generator in such a temperature gradient? Thanks a lots.

Comment: How much power do you need? What is street temperature? Is your device going to touch the street anyway?

Comment: @user253751 it is the air temperature outside the car, around 25~30 deg C

Comment: If you need microwatts, go ahead. If you need more than a few milliwatts, think again.

Comment: the power output i want is around 0.2V. I have tried to read some spec of thermoelectric generator however I can't find its performance at such a relatively low temperature

Comment: thats 0.2W I needs... omg

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks, I am trying to figure out the performance of different ways... is it possible to generate such a power with a peltier have 0.03m^2 in size?

Comment: Look up some TEG data sheets. Google knows. Note that efficiency is low at low delta T Zmax = (Thot-Tcold)/Thot in degrees Kelvin (= degrees C + 273). Actual is a small portion of max. At low delta T 1%-5% is good. Usi g the exhaust sustem will help BUT do not exceed allowed TEG Tmax. Boiling water as a transfer medium can limit Tmax. At say 1% out and 0.2 W you need 20 Watts in which is well inside range of available TEGS.

Comment: Many TEGs via [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=teg+datasheet&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=teg+datasheet&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3303j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Semirandom sample [here](https://thermoelectric-generator.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/SpecTEG1-12611-6.0Thermoelectric-generator1.pdf) would meet your need. | As would [these](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/547732/Data_Sheets/CM35-1.9.pdf)  (from Digikey)  far cheaper are avaiable. | Useful datasheet [here](http://www.rmtltd.ru/datasheets/Thermoelectric_Generators/1md02035_teg.pdf) cost and source unknown.

Comment: Also consider a solar panel, since cars heat up because of the sun.

Comment: Q1: Will the car be being driven? Q2 Where is the device mounted?  || When driven you'll get substantial cooling. What is the application? You can but small wind-turbines specifically designed to clip on the outside of cars and to light LEDs. They are compact and rugged. Also, as user... says, a PV panel may suit (but not at night).

Comment: Thanks for the information about TEG. I am still thinking where to mount it while the could will be driven. I planning to used heat sink for cooling with the air flow during it moves.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, solar panels might be one of the simplest options

Comment: @HinnyTsang Telling us what you are trying to achieve will help us help you far more. Use of a TEG would be inferior to a PV panel in most cases if the obvious limitations of a PV panel (eg needs light) do not matter. A small wind turbine may be superior if the vehicle is always moving when energy is used. Using the vehicle electrics is vastly superior if they exist unless their is good reason not to. SO knowing the real problem will help vastly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for your advice, I would like to construct a self-powered temperature sensor mounting on the surface of a vehicle without modifying its own structure. We will try to use PV panel and wind turbine later.

Comment: @HinnyTsang By telling us a portion of what you are trying to achieve you make it impossible for us to provide a good answer expect by fluke. You'll notice that anyone else has given up and I'm probably going to. This is the first mention of a temperature sensor. You do not say where the data goes - into car, stored in a memory, transferred by radio/wifi/semaphore/ ... . You are wating your time and ours. We can almost certainly answer your real question if we can find out what your real question is. ...

Comment: ... A temperature sensor MAY need to consume almost zero energy and could run on a tiny battery for a year or years. | But as we don't know the aim or application we cannot tell what does or doesn't meet your need.. The answers to your questions are. 1. Yes. 2. Consult data sheets I gave links to. | When you can tell us what you want please advise.